# "play test" won't start

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to start Play 1.2.3 in test mode using `play test` but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class play.Play$Mode.TEST
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:196)
    at play.Play$Mode.valueOf(Play.java:35)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:236)
    at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:158)
```

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: Mac OSX 10.7.4 but someone else had the same problem on Windows (7 I think)

Comment: I am running the same OS and Java and never had a problem...I'll take a look at the source code for some more clues

Comment: `for (Play.Mode c : Play.Mode.values()) System.out.println(c);` shows `DEV` and `PROD`. Does yours have `TEST` also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with a config file that was using *test* as an application mode. Works with `%test.application.mode=dev` instead of `%test.application.mode=test`.